# Something going wrong with the charAt method?

Tags: java

This part of the program is giving me trouble. The file is getting received properly by the program. Without the charAt method the program runs perfectly. I'm not really sure what the issue is. Obviously this is not the program in its entirety, just the part that is giving me an error.

The error:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   0     at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)  at
>   GenSeq.main(GenSeq.java:111)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)

Program:

```
do{
   line = inputStream.nextLine();
   line = line.trim();

   if (line.charAt(0) == '>'){
   //Checking to see if it's an information line
   info = info + line;
   count++;
   //Used to count the number of entries
   }
   else{
     seq = seq + line;
     //Concatenating the sequence together
   }
 while (inputStream.hasNextLine());
 inputStream.close();
```

Edit: We're dealing with DNA and RNA sequences so the only letter it can start with is either A, T, C, G, or U. To handle the blank lines I tried this now. Still getting the error though.

```
do{
       line = inputStream.nextLine();
       char first = line.charAt(0);

       if (first == '>'){
       //Checking to see if it's an information line
       info = info + line;
       count++;
       //Used to count the number of entries
       }

       if (first == 'A' || first == 'T' || first == 'G' || first == 'C' || first == 'U'){
         seq = seq + line;
       }
     }
     while (inputStream.hasNextLine());
     inputStream.close();
```

Comment: Do you have empty lines in your file? What do you expect the behavior to be in that case?

Comment: Can you write `System.out.println(line.charAt(0));`

Comment: Yes. There are empty lines in the file. I was hoping the trim method could handle that.

Comment: The trim method only removes the trailing blank characters, it does not help at all for your exception

Comment: What do you think `trim` does? If you have a line with no content in it, then the `String` is `""`. There's no `charAt(0)`.

Comment: I tried another way to remove the blank lines, but even without the trim method I'm still getting the error. The different code is now in the original post.

Comment: How should I go about getting rid of the lines then? I'm in an introductory Java course... jeez

Comment: That's the question you should be asking. If the line `isEmpty` just `continue`.

Comment: Could I possibly use a nested if and check if the length of the line is greater than 0?

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @Lexi Your new code *still* tries to call `charAt(0)` on a blank line. A blank string has *no characters*, so you cannot call `charAt` on a blank string full stop.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution is to replace `line.charAt(0) == '>'` with `line.startsWith (">")` At least that removes the problem with arrays and you can finish debugging it from there.